# Strange (Cisco) datetime string to SQL datetime

Tags: sql, t-sql, type-conversion

Trying to import a rather unusual formatted datetime sting in SQL.
The Source is an automated export from a Cisco networking-system, I can't alter it's formatting.

The format is Sun Dec 02 03:59:54 CET 2018

Tried datetimefromparts(), convert() combined with substring()'s

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[Cisco2dateTime]
      ( @CDate varchar(28)) RETURNS datetime
    AS
    BEGIN
      RETURN ( datetimefromparts(
                right(@CDate,4), 
                case substring(@CDate,5,3) when 'Jan' then '01' when 'Feb' then '02' when 'Mar' then '03' when 'Apr' then '04' when 'May' then '05' when 'Jun' then '06' when 'Jul' then '07' when 'Aug' then '08' when 'Sep' then '09' when 'Okt' then '10' when 'Nov' then '11' when 'Dec' then '12' END,
                substring(@CDate,9,2),
                substring(@CDate,12,2),
                substring(@CDate,15,2),
                substring(@CDate,18,2),0) )
    END
 GO
```

}

Any idea's how to do this more efficient?

Comment: What RDBMS are you using?  Different platforms handle date/time functions very differently.

Comment: Please tag your question with the proper RDBMS (SQL is not a DBMS), and add the SQL code you have written

Answer (score 0):

If the incoming format is consistent, you can shrink it down to something like this:

```
DECLARE @time NVARCHAR(28) = 'Sun Dec 02 03:59:54 CET 2018'
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING(@time,4,17) + RIGHT(@time,4) AS DATETIME)
```

Returns `2018-12-02 03:59:54.000`

Edited for @Clockwork-Muse

If you want to include the timezone information, you can use a timezone table to match the abbreviations or, if you only have a handful of potential timezones, you can use a table value constructor like in the new example which will return a timezoneoffset:

```
DECLARE @time NVARCHAR(30) = 'Sun Dec 02 03:59:54 CET 2018'

SELECT TODATETIMEOFFSET(CAST(SUBSTRING(@time,4,17) + RIGHT(@time,4) AS DATETIME), z.TZOffset)
FROM 
    (
        VALUES ('CET','+01:00'),('AST','+03:00'),('NZDT','+13:00')
    )AS z(TZName, TZOffset)
WHERE  @time LIKE '%'+z.TZName+'%'
```

Comment: -1: 1) Formatting is heavily dependent on system locale.  Since the Cisco is outputting Central European Time, that format working is not guaranteed.  It's much better to explicitly specify the format, if possible.  2) You're tossing out the offset, so you're immediately losing information as to when the actual event occurred (and/or making it the wrong time altogether).  The conversion needs to include this information, and output `DATETIMEOFFSET`, even if the zone is then converted to UTC.

Comment: @Clockwork-Muse those are valid points but if you notice in the posters example, he is also removing the timezone information. I'm following his precedent in doing so. The results returned by my answer are exactly the same as those returned by the poster's solution. He asked for a more efficient method and that's what I gave him.